# Load images from json url and show in gridview in android

Tags: android, json, gridview, android-imageview

I have created one application.

In that i gets some urls from JSON string and i want to load images from these urls and show in `grid-view`.

My code is:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Screen_Shot.this, screenshotList,
                    R.layout.screen_shot_item, new String[] { "url", "time" }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.imageView_screen_shot, R.id.textView_screen_shot});
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The problem is it shows only time of image captured but not image. Below is my screenshot.

[image: The problem is it shows only time of image captured but not image.]

Comment: So whats ths problem?

Comment: `ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(...)` is this right ??

Comment: State you problem. I guess you clicked on **Ask A Question**. So ask.

Comment: Use this [library](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to solve your issues.

Comment: How to make it possible ?

Comment: I would use this [Library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) is simpler but equally powerful.

Comment: Is there any other option to make it possible ?

Comment: You could to do a custom adapter with a "TextView" and "ImageView".

Comment: Have you any example ?

Comment: Here's an example [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/android-custom-grid-view-example-with-image-and-text.html)

Comment: But i want to load image dynamically from URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this [library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for load dynamically from url one Image.

Example:

> ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourImage);
>     Picasso.with(context).load("YouURL.com").into(img);

Comment: Have you correctly added the library? Show code pless for I help you.

Comment: Picasso.with(context).load(gridViewItems.get(position).get("url")).into(vholder.img);

Comment: It is running successfully without any error. But Image not loading.

Comment: When i click on imagegrid it is show in next activity successfully. But in gridview it is not loading.

Comment: Are you setadapter in your gridview?

Comment: @SagarZala Pless check in the correct answer to give me points.

Comment: `Screen_Shot_Custom_Adapter adapter = new Screen_Shot_Custom_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), screenshotList);          
          gridView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: It gives same output like above screen.

Comment: @SagarZala sorry, If you do not upload all code both the activity as Fragment and adapter can not help you. Edit you post and paste code pless.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46847/discussion-between-sagar-zala-and-terro)